# CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) : No package php-fpm available

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am running on : CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

I want to use nginx as my web server. So I need to install all the Prerequisites.

First

```
# yum -y install epel-release
```

then

```
# yum -y install nginx php-fpm

[root@18010850 conf.d]# yum -y install nginx php-fpm
                        Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
                        Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
                         * EA4: 103.53.192.34
                         * base: mirror.dionipe.net
                         * epel: fedora.dionipe.web.id
                         * extras: mirror.dionipe.net
                         * updates: mirror.dionipe.net
                        Package 1:nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 already                             installed and latest version
                        No package php-fpm available.
                        Nothing to do
```

Why No package php-fpm available. ? I tested by `systemctl status php-fpm`

```
     Unit php-fpm.service could not be found.
```

Please advise

Comment: Try `yum search fpm` and see what you get

Comment: Try yum clean all && yum install php-fpm